# Only first element init as 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have an array, ex:

```
int M[10] = { 1 };
```

I expected M[0] ~ M[9] will all be filled with 1, but when I printed them out, it doesn't, only M[0] is 1, others are 0.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common misconception. Often you see people write things like this

```
int m[10] = { 0 };
```

To "initialise all elements to `0`"; however, really that just initialises the first element to `0` and the rest are default initialised (to 0, which is why it works). Really they could've just written `int m[10] = {};`

You have the same problem: you initialise only the first element to `1` then the rest default to `0`. You can either specify all the parameters, or use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
int m[10] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
int n[10];
std::fill(std::begin(n), std::end(n), 1);
```

Comment: what if I need all elements init to 1? need a for loop to assign it?

Comment: If you need all elements initialised to `1`, you'd use `std::fill` or specify them all. Sorry, was that not clear? You could use a `for` loop as well but there's no reason over something like `std::fill`

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice that. It is clear.